# How to create a 6Ghz hotspot on a rooted Android?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Newer phones now have WiFi 6E, so is it possible to create a 6Ghz hotspot?

I have a rooted Pixel 6 and a laptop, they both have WiFi 6E, so is there any way to create a 6Ghz hotspot?

Comment: A user does not create hotspot. Their system does. They only toggle a setting. In other words, a user is most of the time limited to what their device vendor offered in Settings app. So, which Android device and Android version are you using? What hotspot settings does it offer? Is the device rooted? As of now, the question is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Also, other devices in your vicinity would probably be using legacy 2.4GHz, let alone 5GHz. So a hotspot on a  6GHz alone won't really be useful.

Comment: Newer laptops do have wifi 6e, and yes, I have a rooted device.

Comment: Related for 5Ghz: [How to create 5Ghz hotspot on a rooted Android that doesn't give built in 5Ghz option?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246808/44325)

Answer (score 0):

If your system cannot set a native 6Ghz hotspot, [VPN Hotspot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.mygod.vpnhotspot) is supposed to be able to do exactly that. It requires root and possibly an extra Magisk module. I don't have a routable phone so I can't test it myself.