# How to create 5Ghz hotspot on a rooted Android that doesn't give built in 5Ghz option?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

My Galaxy S8 did have a 5Ghz option on the stock rom, but Lineage OS 19.1 based on Android 12 doesn't have the option to host a 5Ghz hotspot.

Comment: Related for 6GHz: [How to create a 6Ghz hotspot on a rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246785/44325)